# Spring MVC Rest Controller 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am using a Spring MVC (5.3.7) app which has a Rest Controller. When I deploy the war using Intellij or manually on Tomcat 10.0 server, the get url gives me 404. After trying different Spring MVC configs which offcourse didn't work. Finally I resorted to the following config but still no luck

My DispatcherServletInitializer,

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

My DemoConfig class as below used above,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

RestController class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerRestController {
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customerService.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

I have also added index.jsp in webapp folder in classpath which shows the right html (no 404 in route) when war is deployed. Meaning my MVC setup is fine but I don't know why I cannot reach the controller. I am using Java 11, here are the MAVEN dependencies list,

javax.servlet-api - 4.0.1
javax.servlet.jsp-api - 2.3.3
spring-webmvc - 5.3.7 Final
Packaging - war

Comment: Does the log file show Spring being initialized?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the old style of setting things up?

Comment: I am using Mac OSX (Big Sur) and there no Spring initialisation in the logs. All I see after server startup,
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. [2021-05-18 09:26:10,303] Artifact spring-db-rest-demo:war: Artifact is deployed successfully

Comment: This is why - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22414

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Downgrading to Tomcat@9 has done the work for me. Everything seems to working now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. Downgrading to Tomcat@9 has done the work for me. Everything seems to be working now.

Here is the issue link which describes the incompatibility with Spring MVC 5.3.7 and Tomcat@10